# Unterlassung des Genitivs "S"

Tags: genitive

Zurzeit wird im Fernsehen viel über den Islam berichtet und dabei habe ich bemerkt, dass man die Genitivdeklination bei diesem und anderen Wörtern weglässt.

Beispiel:

> Die Gesetze des Islam.

Weitere Beispiele:

> des Barock, des Dativ, des Dynamo, des Festival, des Film, des Indiz.

Ich erkenne hier keine grammatikalische Regel, die besagt, dass man hier die entsprechende Deklination weglassen solle.

Nur bei Vokabeln, die eine N-Deklination bekommen, ist mir bewusst, dass das S nicht mehr hinzuzufügen ist.

Beispiel:

> der Beamte > des Beamten
>
> der Elefant > des Elefanten

Weshalb wird also bei vielen Wörtern das zu deklinierende S weggelassen?

Comment: Das Wort "unterlassen" wird nur für Handlungen verwendet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Abkürzungen und Fremdwörter haben im Deutschen kunterbunte Deklinationsformen - sie lassen sich typischerweise nicht in eine der Deklinationsklassen einordnen. Vor allem Namen von Organisationen und Firmen (das trifft hier vielleicht teilweise zu) werden oft überhaupt nicht dekliniert.

Es muss allerdings festgehalten werden, dass der Duden und andere Wörterbücher der Ansicht sind, dass der [Islam](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Islam) ein -s im Genitiv bekommen soll/kann.

Ähnliches gilt für "Barock", das sowohl mit als auch (wohl sogar häufiger) ohne Genitiv-s verwendet werden kann. Eine Erklärung dafür findet sich in einer älteren Duden-Ausgabe:

> Das Weglassen des Genitiv-s tritt häufig dann auf, wenn es sich um ein Fremdwort handelt, welches als Eigenname, Fachwort oder Bezeichnung für Gattungen verwendet wird. (Vgl. Duden 9, S. 1007)

Speziell für das Wort "Barock" schreibt der Duden, dass das Weglassen der Genitiv-Endung "standardsprachlich anerkannt" sei.

Deine anderen Beispiele sind teilweise ganz einfach falsch:

- des Dativs
- des Dynamos
- des Festivals
- des Films
- des Indizes

Comment: Cool - Danke :)